# inferential statistics methods for population?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Is that true to use inferential statistics methods when we study whole population? I mean for example is that true to use hypothesis test when whole population are under study? 
Suppose I am studying whole students of a class( I did not select any sample from them). Suppose my goal is to see if there is a relationship between background family and the scores of math course. My variables are background family (poor/rich) and scores ( any number between 0 to 100). Now my question is : 
Is that true to test correlation of these two variables =0 or not? In other words can I use inferential statistics method? Since I am dealing with whole population will it be correct to do test hypothesis? Or since I have whole population, then only descriptive statistical method can be used?

Comment: This question has already been answered in [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com): http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2628/10259